# Why Won't Google API V3 Return Children?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, http-error

I want to use Python to get a list of all the files/folders in a given folder in Google Drive. The call I'm using is this:

```
query = parentID + " in parents"

response = service.files().list(q=query,
                                spaces='drive',
                                fields='files(id, name, parents)').execute()
```

According to the [search for files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters#fields) documentation and the [migrating to v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#methods) documentation, I should be doing it correctly. But when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=[MY_PARENT_ID]+in+parents&spaces=drive&alt=json&fields=files%28id%2C+name%2C+parents%29 returned "Invalid Value">
```

What is wrong with my query and how would I call this correctly?

Comment: Mistaken tag. Thank you for fixing

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After trying for some 15 hours, found this solution:

just change the *query* variable as follows
suppose parent id is '0B_hg54vjh34v5jh23gv5i2v35th2gv35v235kjvk'

```
query="'0B_hg54vjh34v5jh23gv5i2v35th2gv35v235kjvk' in parents"
```

now, it should work.

it should work even if you interchange single and double quotes..what you were using results into `query="0B_hg54vjh34v5jh23gv5i2v35th2gv35v235kjvk in parents"` while what we need is `query="'0B_hg54vjh34v5jh23gv5i2v35th2gv35v235kjvk' in parents"`

alternative way of doing this is:

```
parentId='0B_hg54vjh34v5jh23gv5i2v35th2gv35v235kjvk'
query="'" + "' in parents"
```

Why is this happening :- 
If you look at your output error properly,
It has a http link which looks like this:
`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=0B_hg54vjh34v5jh23gv5i2v35th2gv35v235kjvk+in+parents&spaces=drive&alt=json&fields=files%28id%2C+name%2C+parents%29`

but the required one has single quotes around the Id and looks like this:

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='0B_hg54vjh34v5jh23gv5i2v35th2gv35v235kjvk'+in+parents&spaces=drive&alt=json&fields=files%28id%2C+name%2C+parents%29`

Comment: How is that different than what I was trying? E.g. If I did `query = parentID + " in parents"` and `parentId='0B_hg54vjh34v5jh23gv5i2v35th2gv35v235kjvk'`, then `query = parentID + " in parents"` is the same as `query="'0B_hg54vjh34v5jh23gv5i2v35th2gv35v235kjvk' in parents"` right? Or is the difference the single quotes within the double-quoted string?

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense

Comment: This is one of the most confusing ways I've ever come across to list the contents of a folder and the documentation is not clear on this point at all. Thank you!

Comment: wow, i never would have figured this out. this is the most cryptic api in the world.