# Deleting file from google share drive using pydrive, file exist, but API return 404 File not found error

Tags: python, pydrive

I am trying to delete a file on a shared drive using pydrive, but I cannot delete the file.
When I get the information about the file on the drive, it shows the file ID, but when I use "Trash() function", it shows an error as "File not found: XXX".

Development environment

```
ubuntu 20.04 on docker
python 3.7
pydrive 1.3.1
```

Code contents

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
gauth.credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("client_secrets.json", scope)
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

for f in drive.ListFile({'driveId': 'AAA', 'corpora': 'drive', 'includeItemsFromAllDrives': 'true',
 'supportsAllDrives': 'true', 'q': 'title = "lock" and trashed = false'}).GetList():
    print(f['title'], '  \t', f['id'])

    f_txt = drive.CreateFile(f)
    f_txt.Trash()
```

Error contents

```
root@test:~/reman/src/For_lambda/refer# python3 delete_lockfile.py 
lock     10xM-FIkMoyRIb7PC1VBxZZJn_QePxy-I
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/files.py", line 410, in _FilesTrash
    http=self.http)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 915, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError:
 <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/10xM-FIkMoyRIb7PC1VBxZZJn_QePxy-I/trash?alt=json returned 
"File not found: 10xM-FIkMoyRIb7PC1VBxZZJn_QePxy-I". 
Details: "File not found: 10xM-FIkMoyRIb7PC1VBxZZJn_QePxy-I">
```

As shown above, I am able to get [fileid: **10xM-FIkMoyRIb7PC1VBxZZJn_QePxy-I**], but when I delete the file, it shows up as Not found.

I have no idea what is going on. Please help! Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874223/why-wont-google-api-v3-return-children

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not uploading the file. With `drive.CreateFile(f)` you are creating an `GoogleDriveFile` instance but you have to use the `Upload()` method to do so. That's why it shows you that `File not found` exception. You could try something like this inside your `for`:

```
    f_txt = drive.CreateFile(f)
    f_txt.Upload()
    f_txt.Trash()
```

Comment: Thank you for support. I tried above contents. But happen similar error at **Upload function**.
error is following.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delete_lockfile.py", line 18, in <module>
    f_txt.Upload()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/files.py", line 239, in FetchMetadata
    raise ApiRequestError(error)
pydrive.files.ApiRequestError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/10xM-FIkMoyRIb7PC1VBxZZJn_QePxy-I?alt=json returned "File not found: 10xM-FIkMoyRIb7PC1VBxZZJn_QePxy-I".`